# How to create local DNS zone in BIND?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, dns-record

Can anyone help me regarding a BIND9 recursive DNS server?

The server is functioning correctly in relation to recursion. I need to create a local, static ZONE entry for a given host.

No inbound working like this:

```
 local-zone: "domain.name." static

 local-date: "voip.xxx.com.br IN A x.x.x.x"
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this in BIND?

Comment: And you can't just create a zone (every zone on a local server is local), because of what?

Comment: My doubt is that I can not do exactly the same is in unbound.

Comment: @bjoster
Did you understand what I need?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the actual goal and what you have tried? The way the problem is currently stated it sounds like you should be able to just create a normal zone? An alternative interpretation (reading between the lines) could be that you do not actually want a zone at all but override a specific record, for which you could use RPZ.